# Override An Existing Property as a Child form of its return type

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, inheritance, overriding

I apologize if that title is confusing. This question may be a result of lack of coffee and/or sleep, but my mind is not working correctly right now.

Anyways, I have an inheritance tree like so (I know the architecture isn't ideal):

```
BaseClass

GeneralForm : Inherits BaseClass

SpecificForm : Inherits GeneralForm
```

And an object like so:

```
MyItem

MySpecificItem : Inherits MyItem
```

I have `Items As List (Of MyItem)` as a property in `BaseClass`. I would like for `SpecificForm` to somehow override `Items` to return type `List (Of MySpecificItem)`. I feel like this is easy to do, but again, my head is spinning and I can't think straight at the moment.

Thanks so much in advance.

**EDIT**

If the above isn't possible, is it possible to take a `List (Of MyItem)` and turn it into a `List (Of MySpecificItem)`? `MySpecificItem` has just one additional property that is specific to `SpecificForm`, but I NEED it.

Anyone? :\

Comment: this isn't impossible, is it??

Answer (score 0):

You should be able in `SpecificForm` to just do the following...

```
Private pMySpecificItems As List(Of MySpecificItem)

Public Shadows ReadOnly Property Items() As List(Of MySpecificItem) 
    Get 
        Return pMySpecificItems
    End Get 
End Property
```

The 'Shadows' keyword will tell the compiler that this property in SpecificForm hides the Items property from the base-class form.

You can't actually delegate to the base class' property and "cast" it to `List(Of MySpecificItem)` because while a sub-class may be viewed as an instance of its base class, a base class object cannot be cast to an instance of a sub-class (as the sub-class may have added required properties/state that the base class does not support or implement).